# Plant part adaptation vs animals

Tags: human-physiology, transplantation

I have seen nurseries selling plants that grow to trees bearing different fruits. Eg: A single plant that produces fruits of peach, plum, apricot,etc. Here is one [website](https://www.fruitsaladtrees.com/) that advertises such trees. So in conclusion any tree could be grafted to live in a trunk of a similar kind of tree. How come animal parts cannot be transplanted with other animals of the same kind. Why is it not possible to use any animal organs for humans using transplants.

Comment: Because humans have an immune system.

Comment: Can you elaborate?